# C# and Ubuntu - How do I get size of primary screen?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ubuntu, mono

I'm trying to determine the size of my primary screen so I can capture its image.  My setup is a laptop that has a 1600x900 display, and an external monitor that's 1920x1080.  The code that gets the size runs fine on Windows, but gives the wrong result on Ubuntu (using MonoDevelop).

```
    Rectangle capture_rect = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Console.WriteLine("width={0} height={1}", capture_rect.Height, capture_rect.Width);
```

The result on Ubuntu is "width=3520 height=1080".  If I disconnect the external monitor, I get the correct result, which is "width=1600 height=900".  Any idea why I get the wrong value on Ubuntu with multiple displays?

Comment: Apparently, Ubuntu thinks that your external monitor is the primary screen. Have you look at the Ubuntu's screen properties to confirm that it is configured as you expect (external monitor not being the primary screen)?

Comment: The return value 3520x1080 is a rectangle that encompasses the size of both displays.  If I go to System Settings > Displays, it doesn't say anything about primary vs. secondary display, but my "Launcher Placement" is set for my laptop display.  Is there somewhere else I should look for screen properties?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too experienced in Mono/Ubuntu and don't have an Ubuntu computer with me now; this was just a generic suggestion (i.e., the most likely problem is that PrimaryScreen.Bounds is actually rightly calculated but it points to other screen). In your situation, I would do some tests with all the screens recognised by the Screen class to see how they are stored/recognised; also would do some research in the Ubuntu forums. Sorry but cannot be of further help.

Comment: What happens if you loop over Screen.AllScreens? Any more data in there?

Comment: Screen.AllScreens has only one entry, and it's the same as Screen.PrimaryScreen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using .NET to get the screen dimensions, I used Linux "xrandr".  Here's my code:

```
public Rectangle GetDisplaySize()
{
    // Use xrandr to get size of screen located at offset (0,0).
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "xrandr";
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(output, @"(\d+)x(\d+)\+0\+0");
    var w = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var h = match.Groups[2].Value;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    r.Width = int.Parse(w);
    r.Height = int.Parse(h);
    Console.WriteLine ("Display Size is {0} x {1}", w, h);
    return r;
}
```